# WPF ItemsPanelTemplate resource not being applied

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I am in the process of learning WPF and I am trying to create a graph via a ListBox as described [here](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cnagel/2011/06/wpf-listbox-as-bar-chart.html).

Everything is working as expected, apart from the graph (ItemsPanel) isn't rotated 90 degrees as it should be.

The DataContext is simply a `ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<double, int>>`.

Here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="XNM.GUI.Graph"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="XNM" MinHeight="400" MinWidth="600" Height="400" Width="600"
    Icon="..\Resources\XNM2.ico"
    Style="{DynamicResource SkinWindowStyle}">   
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="5" Margin="10" Padding="5"
        CornerRadius="5">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"
             ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource BarChartItemTemplate}"
             ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource BarChartItemsPanel}" />

    </Grid>
</Border>
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BarChartItemTemplate">
        <Border Width="200" Height="50">
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle Fill="Red" StrokeThickness="0" 
                           Height="40" Width="{Binding Value}" Margin="3" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <Rectangle.LayoutTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="20" />
                    </Rectangle.LayoutTransform>
                </Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Margin="20" FontWeight="Bold" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    Text="{Binding Key}">
                    <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1" ScaleY="1" />
                    </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="BarChartItemsPanel">
        <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True">
            <VirtualizingStackPanel.LayoutTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1" ScaleY="1" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </VirtualizingStackPanel.LayoutTransform>
        </VirtualizingStackPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Here is the code behind for completeness:

```cs
public partial class Graph : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<SensorData> _sensorData;

    public Graph(ObservableCollection<SensorData> sensorData)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this._sensorData = sensorData;
        CreateGraph();
    }

    private void CreateGraph()
    {
        if (this._sensorData.Any())
        {
            this.DataContext = this._sensorData[0].CollatedResults;
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone please point out what could be causing the issue here. Whenever I have used Templates before, I haven't had this kind of issue, so I'm a bit stumped.

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

I have found out that it was a style that was causing the issue, in particular the `ControlTemplate` part of the XAML below:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ControlBackgroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                            CornerRadius="2" 
                            Background="{DynamicResource ControlBackgroundBrush}" />
                    <ScrollViewer Margin="1" 
                            Style="{DynamicResource NuclearScrollViewer}" 
                            Focusable="false" Background="{x:Null}">
                        <StackPanel Margin="1,1,1,1" IsItemsHost="true" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" 
                             Value="{DynamicResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" 
                             TargetName="Border" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" 
                             Value="{DynamicResource DisabledBorderBrush}" 
                             TargetName="Border" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now due to my lack of knowledge with styles, I am unsure why this is having this effect, but when I comment out the `ControlTemplate` part, it works as expected, admittedly with obviously style issues with other ListBoxes.

Does anyone know why this is causing the result I am experiencing? Hopefully I can figure it out myself, but I think it will be a while until I understand styles to that degree!

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting a `BindingExpression` error in your `Debug.Out` window in VS?

Comment: `<Window.Resources>` tag is usually placed BEFORE any other content.

Comment: @DHN I'm getting no errors in my `Debug.Out`. @HighCore Quite probably, this is very much a learning experience for me so I haven't paid much attention to the formatting!

Comment: @XN16 my point is, try reversing that and placing resources above the rest of the content and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @HighCore I tried what you suggested, and unfortunately it made no difference.

Comment: @XN16 Are you sure, that the `DataContext` is set? Seems to be the only possible error left.

Comment: @DHN Yep, `DataContext` is definitely set as I am getting results on screen, it's just that the rotation that the `BarChartItemsPanel` should perform isn't doing anything as far as I can tell.